# Adding an Array to a UITableView, using a UINavigationController on a Tab Bar based application

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have made simple cocoa touch apps before but I have never used UINavigationControllers, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to add an array of a list of store names to a UITableView. The UITableView is accessed through a UINavigation controller by a tab on a tab bar.

I have a TabBarController.xib file that holds the tab bar.
I also have a AtoZNavigationController.xib that holds the UINavigationController.
And I have a AtoZTableController.xib file that holds the UITableView.

*This is my AppDelegate.h:*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class AtoZNavigationController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet AtoZNavigationController *navController;

@end
```

*The AppDelegate.m*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AtoZNavigationController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize rootController;
@synthesize navController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil];
  [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
@end
```

*The AtoZNavigationController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AtoZNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

*The AtoZNavigationController.m*

```
#import "AtoZNavigationController.h"

@interface AtoZNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation AtoZNavigationController

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

*The AtoZTableController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AtoZTableController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,       UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *AtoZTableView;
    NSMutableArray *AtoZArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *AtoZTableView;
@end
```

*The AtoZTableController.h*

```
#import "AtoZTableController.h"

@interface AtoZTableController ()

@end

@implementation AtoZTableController
@synthesize AtoZTableView;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"A to Z", @"An A to Z List of Stores");

     AtoZArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Apple"];
    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Boots"];
    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Topman"];
}

 -(void)viewDidUnload
{
     [super viewDidUnload];
     // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
     // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [AtoZArray count];
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [AtoZArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AtoZTableController.h`, you have a problem.

The problem is in your 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' method.
Here's what you have:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [AtoZArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that you never handle for a return value of `nil` from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier`.

Try this out:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // What happens if you don't get a cell to use?
    // This is the way to create a new, default UITableViewCell
    if (!cell) {            
        // You can look at the UITableViewCell class reference to see the 4 available styles
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [AtoZArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

---

**Edit/Update:**

OK, so it's a little bit difficult to know exactly where your error is, so I'll set up/describe for you a typical situation (or how I'd do it in your shoes).

If you create a new app and select the "Tabbed Application" template in Xcode, you get the following method in your app delegate (more or less; I condensed it a little bit and "fixed" Apple's poor choice to use dot notation):

***Note:*** I believe the problem you're having with pushing a new view controller will be fixed below now...***End Note***

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
    // New line...
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    [[self setTabBarController:[[UITabBarController alloc] init]];
    // Change here, too...
    [[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navC, vc2, nil]];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:[self tabBarController]];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This method sets up all you need to launch your app with 2 UIViewControllers created and set as tab 1 and tab 2 inside of a UITabBarController.

Now, you can make FirstViewController and SecondViewController be whatever you want. For purposes of this question, we'll assume that you want to alter FirstViewController to host a UITableView, which will push a detail UIViewController when a user selects a row on the screen.

**Requirements**
*EITHER* FirstViewController must be a subclass of UITableViewController (this is *not* what the default template provides) *OR* you must add a UITableView onto FirstViewController's view and set up all of the connections.

Let's assume you're going to keep FirstViewController as a standard UIViewController subclass and that you'll add a UITableView onto its view. (I'd probably change it to a UITableViewController subclass, but that might be more confusing at this point.)

First, in FirstViewController.h, change this:

```
@interface MMFirstViewController : UIViewController 
@end
```

to this:

```
@interface MMFirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *TableView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;
@end
```

Next, in FirstViewController.m, synthesize the TableView property (`@synthesize TableView`).
Next, click on FirstViewController.xib in Xcode to have it load up in Interface Builder (I'm assuming here that you're using Xcode 4).
Now, drag a UITableView from the controls panel onto your UIViewController's view.
Make the following connections in Interface Builder:

1. Right click on `File's Owner` and connect the TableView property to the UITableView you dropped on the view of FirstViewController.
2. Right click on the UITableView and connect **BOTH** the `datasource` **AND** `delegate` properties to `File's Owner`.

Now, the code you posted initializing and populating `AtoZArray` should work fine. Don't forget to copy in the 3 UITableView methods you previously had, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Those steps should get you working and should also let you see where you perhaps went wrong in your setup. Please note, you'll still have to figure out `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` on your own in order to push in your new UIViewController.

Here's a teaser to get you started:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    ThirdViewController *detailVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your method but the UITableView is still displaying blank cells. I think it may be a problem with my connections in the .xib files. I tried to post some images but as I'm a new member I can't. I'll try to explain the best I can:

Comment: Well, just make sure you've set up the `data source` and `delegate` connections in IB.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your method but the UITableView is still displaying blank cells. I think it may be a problem with my connections in the .xib files. I tried to post some images but as I'm a new member I can't. Do I need link in all 3 .xib files? The TabBarController.xib, the AtoZNavigationController.xib and the AtoZTableController? I've tried some variations but I'm unsure if there's an error in the code or links. The app build O.K and the title of the UITableView can be modified in the AtoZTableController.m fle. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Thanks for that. Finally managed to get it to work, one thing I wasn't doing was specifying the number of sections, I had it set to 0. Am I right in thinking each new page I add would be a new section?Thanks again for your help. Now just to get it into my original...

Comment: Also, that method REALLY did give me a better understanding of how the tab bar is created programatically. Thanks again man, really appreciated it.

Comment: OK, so I created a new UIViewController with a label to test if the navigation was working. I entered the navigation logic teaser code you gave me, but when I tap on a row it still remains highlighted and doesn't continue to the new UIViewController I created. The UIVIewController simply has a label on it. Am I right in thinking if I've done it correctly tapping on a row should open the view displaying the label? Should the new file be a UINavigationController? Would that not only be the case if I was to create another detail level in the new controller?

Comment: Also, is there anyway I can post this as a new question in the website, while insuring you can see it, to improve your rating for helping me again? I'm new to the site.

Comment: Also, for the selection issue, try `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES/NO]`.

Comment: OK thanks, I've up voted the answer but I can't see how to do it for each comment? It seems my touch events aren't being handled? Do I need to set them up manually? I assumed the UITableNavigation class would handle that automatically?

Comment: @mdm30075 Still doesn't open the new view it just removes the highlight. I might have to raise a new question because I'm being warned of extended discussions and don't have enough rep to chat. Thanks for your help thus far anyway.

Comment: Yes, touch events are automatic. Sorry, posted the comment about the edit before the edit... probably was confusing... ;-) Gotta run for now... I'll check in later to see if you got it working

Answer (score 1):

I  had to create an instance of the navigationController and pass that into the subview in my appDelegate.m along with the tabBarController. It can then later be referenced in my UITableViewController.

Here's the code I added:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_tabBarController];
[self.window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Where navigationController is simply an instance of a subclass of either UITableViewController or UIViewController, depending on what type of screen you want to display.